# How to compare two datetimes with time zone offset using javascript (comparison greater than or less than)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a scenario where I need to compare Date1 and Date2 
where `Date1 = 05.01.2008 6:00 +5:00` 
and `Date2 = 05.01.2008 7:00 +5:00`
I am not getting a way to convert these `datetimeoffsets` to a particular conversion format. Plz help.
Here is what all i have tried till now

```
function validate()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById("txtDate1").innerHTML;
        var b = document.getElementById("txtDate2").innerHTML;
        if (a > b) {
            alert('greater')
        }
        else {
            alert('Smaller')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code. using `Date.parse`

```js
var date1 = new Date(Date.parse("05.01.2008 6:00 +5:00"));
var date2 = new Date(Date.parse("05.01.2008 7:00 +5:00"));

    if (date1 < date2) {
      alert('Smaller')
    } else if (date1 > date2) {
      alert('greater')
    } else {
       alert("date1 === date2");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, can you shed some light on how can we change the date format to dd.MM.YYYY HH:MM +/-Offset ?

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to parse them as Date objects for comparison. One popular option is using `moment.js`, since it can interpret many formats.
Then you can compare them by using `Date.prototype.getTime` function to get the Unix timestamp, which all use the same time zone.

The way you compare them at the moment is as String types, which will not work.